# How do I get users to only view their lists with ruby and sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My ruby and sinatra app currently lets users view and edit all lists created and I haven't been able to figure out how to only show lists to the user who created them.

Here is what my lists_controller looks like:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController 

 get "/lists" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in
  @lists = List.all
  erb :'lists/index'
 end

 get "/lists/new" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in 
  @error_message = params[:error]
  erb :'lists/new'
 end

 get "/lists/:id/edit" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in 
  @error_message = params[:error]
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
  erb :'lists/edit'
 end

 delete '/lists/:id/delete' do
  @list = List.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @list.delete
  redirect to '/lists'
 end

 post "/lists/:id" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in 
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
  unless List.valid_params?(params)
    redirect "/lists/#{@list.id}/edit?error=invalid list"
  end
  @list.update(params.select{|a|a=="todo_name"|| a=="todo_list"})
  redirect "/lists/#{@list.id}"
 end

 get "/lists/:id" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in 
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
  erb :'lists/show'
 end

 post "/lists" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in 
  unless List.valid_params?(params)
    redirect "/lists/new?error=invalid list"
  end
  List.create(params)
  redirect "/lists"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies within

```
@lists = List.all
```

In Rails w/ ActiveRecord (assuming your `List` model `belongs_to` the `User`) you can instead do something like

```
@lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and now when I create a new list the list is not displayed on my lists page.

Comment: Is it possible to share how your List object is defined?